# I can't execute roslanch of remote PC from host PC

Tags: ros, roslaunch, remote, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I'd like to execute simple roslaunch file(test1.launch) of remote PC from host PC.Then I encountered the following error.please let me know how to resolve the problem.

```
started roslaunch server http://mori:44595/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /rosdistro: indigo
 * /rosversion: 1.11.21

NODES
  /
    test1 (test1/test1_node)

ERROR: unable to contact ROS master at [http://NotePC:11311]
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
```

I configured something as the following procedure.

> [1] setting of IP Address and name

```
on Host(NotePC)
I executed "sudo gedit /etc/hosts" and save the following parameter
    192.168.122.22 NotePC
    192.168.122.33 mori

on remote PC(mori)
I executed same command.
    192.168.122.22 NotePC
    192.168.122.33 mori
```

> [2] start roscore
> I executed the following command to start roscore in host(NotePC)

```
export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://NotePC:11311 
roscore
```

> [3] connect to remotePC

```
ssh mori@mori -p 22
export ROS_HOSTNAME=mori
export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://NotePC:11311 
export ROSLAUNCH_SSH_UNKNOWN=1
roslaunch test1 test1.launch
```

Then I encountered above error. test1.launch file is following.

```
<launch>
 <machine name="mori" address="mori" env-loader="/home/mori/catkin_ws/devel/env.sh" user="mori" password="my_pass"/>   
 <node  machine="mori" pkg="test1" type="test1_node" name="test1" output="screen"/>
</launch>
```

My "/home/mori/catkin_ws/devel/env.sh" is the following.

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
# generated from catkin/cmake/templates/env.sh.in

if [ $# -eq 0 ] ; then
/bin/echo "Usage: env.sh COMMANDS"
/bin/echo "Calling env.sh without arguments is not supported anymore. Instead spawn a subshell and source a   setup file manually."
exit 1
fi

# ensure to not use different shell type which was set before
CATKIN_SHELL=sh

# source setup.sh from same directory as this file
_CATKIN_SETUP_DIR=$(cd "`dirname "$0"`" > /dev/null && pwd)
. "$_CATKIN_SETUP_DIR/setup.sh"
exec "$@"
```

I checked the following contents.

```
(1) Ping test:I executed "ping NotePC" in remote PC . Then I succeed.
(2) I executed "echo $ROS_HOSTNAME" after the step [3].
        >mori
(3) I executed "echo $ROS_MASTER_URI  after the step [3].
       >http://NotePC:11311
(4) I  succeed execution of the command "rosrun test1 test1_node" after step[3].
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/281063/i-can%27t-execute-roslanch-of-remote-pc-from-host-pc/) by [sasadasd](https://answers.ros.org/users/27743/sasadasd/) on ROS Answers with karma: 104 on 2018-01-27

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found that  I should set "ROS_IP" on each PC. After I configured it , I can execute roslaunch from remote PC.

---

Originally posted by [sasadasd](https://answers.ros.org/users/27743/sasadasd/) with karma: 104 on 2018-01-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1